# Prettier putting if statement on one line

Tags: prettier

Prettier formats if statement without curley braces into one line.

This means that this :

```
function getErrorMessage(response) {
    let errorMessage = null;

    if (!response.originalError.response) 
        errorMessage = 'network error';
    else 
        errorMessage = response.originalError.response.data.errorMessage;

    return errorMessage;
}
```

becomes this :

```
function getErrorMessage(response) {
    let errorMessage = null;

    if (!response.originalError.response) errorMessage = 'network error';
    else errorMessage = response.originalError.response.data.errorMessage;

    return errorMessage;
}
```

which is ***FAR*** more unreadable.

Is there a way of disabling this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question (which I upvoted), but your function can be made simpler and even more readable (and ever so slightly more efficient), by eliminating your `errorMessage` variable entirely. https://gist.github.com/flimzy/78be389b85d37ba7536daf5e858b8ca7

Comment: yes, i agree, just wanted to use my code as an illustration

Comment: Possibly not what you want to hear, but how about adding curly braces? IMO they should be there anyway.

Comment: yes i added curly braces. That fixed it. But I don't understand why prettier would do such an ugly formatting

Comment: @OliverWatkins Might be a case of passive-aggressive "my way or the highway" to enforce the style of superfluous paratheses in combination with (and here's my evil assumption) ridicule alternative. It's like saying *you don't have to use curlies on single-statement* but then adding a "proof" of it being wrong by *but this is the ugliness you'll get*. It's such a great package so it's a shame they are so inflexible. See the answer for details.

Answer (score 6):

As asked in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65697539/prettier-forces-curlyless-single-line-if-statement-to-be-on-the-same-line-inste?noredirect=1#comment116175207_65697539), it turns out that the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65721310/1525840) is that you can not and will not be able to.

As for the WFT that an average senses, well... Apparently, *opinionated* doesn't mean *respected and well-considered in opinion of many*. It means that it's *implementing the author's opinion*.

So, surprisingly, the unexpected thing isn't the lack of configurability but rather that there are any options to be set at all! Go figure... Someone should create a new package called *EvenPrettier* or *FexiblyPrettier* and fork in more options. If I only knew how, I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using **Beautify - HookyQR** extension for vscode
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify

**Example Settings**

File: .jsbeautifyrc

```
{
    "brace_style": "collapse,preserve-inline",
    "max_preserve_newlines": 2,
    "end_with_newline": false
}
```

**Example Code**

File: a.js

```
function dfs(start) {

    if (start > n)
        return;

    ans.push(start);

    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        dfs(start * 10 + i);

}
```